# Python3 updating the wrong variable Dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Thanks for taking your time to read my issue.

I have a coding scenario were I have an **original** dictionary. I set that original dictionary into a **new** variable, which from my understanding is spawning a clone of that object.

When I create a second dictionary, and use the update function of the new dict to merge the second dict, it updates the **original** dict and the **new** dict. I expect it to only update the **new** variable dict while perserving the **original** dict.

See a code example below:

```
dict1 = {"main": "test1"}
dict2 = {"sub": "test2"}
dict_combo = dict1
dict_combo.update(dict2)
print(dict1)
print(dict_combo)
```

Results:

```
$ python3 test_dict.py 
{'main': 'test1', 'sub': 'test2'}
{'main': 'test1', 'sub': 'test2'}
```

What I expect to see:

```
$ python3 test_dict.py 
{'main': 'test1'}
{'main': 'test1', 'sub': 'test2'}
```

As you can see, both dict1 and dict_combo are being updated when I am only updating the dict object called dict_combo.

Can someone explain why my expectation is wrong? Why is *dict1* being updated?

Comment: ``dict_combo = dict1`` creates an alias, not a copy, of ``dict1``. There is only one single ``{"main": "test1"}`` known by two names.

Comment: This is a good reference on how variables work in Python: https://realpython.com/python-variables/#object-references   When you assign an object to a "variable" you're really just creating a new pointer to an existing object.  Python has no concept of copying on assignment.

Comment: Hey! Thank you both for your reply! That explains my misunderstanding. Thanks for the link @Iguananaut